# python list plus list

Tags: python, list

```
x = PyramidROIAlign([pool_size, pool_size],
                    name="roi_align_classifier")([rois, image_meta] + feature_maps)
```

In the codes above, is the `[rois, image_meta] + feature_maps` same as `[rois, image_meta, feature_maps]`? What is the difference?

Thanks.

Comment: An equivalent expression would be `[rois, image_meta, *feature_maps]`, if you wanted to take advantage of unpacking.

Comment: What do you get when you try sample lists, using each syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `len` as a tool to show what the results of those two different expressions would be:

`len([rois, image_meta] + feature_maps)` is equal to `2 + len(feature_maps)`
`len([rois, image_meta, feature_maps])` is equal to `3`.

`+` is the list concatenation operator. If you add `feature_maps` as the last element of the list, you will have a list inside of a list. If you concatenate `feature_maps` to the list, it will add all of the elements of `feature_maps` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If `feature_maps` is `[x, y, z, ...]`,

then `[rois, image_meta] + feature_maps` is `[rois, image_meta, x, y, z...]`